# What's the pattern name for: optional action menu after input

Tags: contextual-menu

Looking for a pattern name for an action menu that can be opened after input. Visual Studio has this when you for example change a name and you get visual indicator that you can press Ctrl + . to open a small action menu (see below). We are thinking of using this pattern in our web application so the user has the option to do like "Apply to all." once input is valid.

[image]

=>

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the pattern name you are looking for is a Context Menu. Tradionally they are accessed via right click or ctrl click but in this case the trigger appears to be a hover or key down.

http://tworivers.com/blog/archives/489

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right. Although context menu is more or less associated with "right clicking the mouse". I though it might exist a more precis term for this, as it's only accessible during specific conditions. Another product uses the term _action list_.