# Proper name for autosuggest pattern of partial content within a field (#tags or @mentions)

Tags: design-patterns, autocomplete

Autocomplete/autosuggest (or, sometimes, ["Filter as you type"](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/20660/74888) or "typeahead") all seem to generally refer to [the pattern of filling a whole text input field with the results from a suggestion list.](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/Autocomplete)

[image: google autocomplete example]

Is there a name specifically for the similar (but slightly different) pattern of suggesting individual items in a larger text input field, usually triggered by a particular initial character (as with #tags or @mentions)?

[image: at-mention auto-suggest in GitHub issues]

Edit: Somewhat similar to what is [could be called a "context menu"](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/67774/whats-the-pattern-name-for-optional-action-menu-after-input), but again that generally refers to something else (actions menu available after a right-click)

Comment: Great first question and good examples! I would just call all of this "autocomplete" but I am not a UX designer by trade.

Comment: @StevenNoto Thanks! I was thinking of it as autocomplete too, but googling for that seemed to almost exclusively bring up examples like the first google one or selecting an item from a dropdown. So figured I'd see if any of the experts here had any better ideas :) I was thinking something like "inline auto-suggest" would make sense, but the [few](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Chrome-like-jQuery-Autocomplete-Autosuggest-Plugin-typeAhead/) [references](http://polarblau.github.io/suggest/) I found to that seemed to describe showing only the first suggested result as text within the input.

Comment: An IDE would call it "code completion" but that's too specific

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a particular name for it.

It's still auto-suggestion or auto-completion except its relevance is *localised* to the immediate context (typically single words) rather than affecting the entire phrase.

This type of feature might have additional smart behaviours for the specific context and be given a marketing name, like some kind of assistant - e.g. like [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/features/default.asp), but I don't believe there's a specific name for this action in the scope of larger content.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's still called as ' tag auto suggestion' or '  comment auto suggestion'